# es_extended/server/functions.lua:401: attempt to index a nil value (local 'item’)

Tags: fivem, esx

So everything was working just fine until earlier when i imported some items into my sql, but now everytime someones using the ak-47 drug script it doesnt finish the function, also giving the two errors i gave above for both the scripts they alternate which dvript gives the error, retraced my steps and removed the 3 scripts that i recently added and also deleted everything that was added from the sql, still getting this error please help

Trued retracing my step and uninstalling everythig its still giving me that eroor